# Endless adapter for ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I've been using [CWAC's EndlessAdapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless) to achieve infinite scrolling on ListViews.

I'd like to accomplish the equivalent for a ViewPager. Unfortunately, PageAdapter and ListAdapter do not share the same common base class.

What's the best way to go about this? Does a library exist that already handles this?

Comment: If you have implemented, please share your solution on gitHub or anywhere you like :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> What's the best way to go about this?

Add "endless" logic to your own implementation of `PagerAdapter`. Or, if you wish, try creating a decorating `PagerAdapter`, the way that `EndlessAdapter` decorates a regular `Adapter`.

The latter is likely to be tricky, given that `PagerAdapter` is designed for pages to be views or fragments, and the fragment handling inside of classes like `FragmentPagerAdapter` is a bit scary.

> Does a library exist that already handles this?

None that I am aware of.

Mainly, that is because the use case doesn't seem as compelling. With a `ListView`, the user can fling the list, scrolling through dozens or hundreds of rows very quickly. Hence, using "we got to the end" as the trigger to load more data seems reasonable. With a `ViewPager`, though, it typically takes a lot longer to get to the end, particularly if you are not using `PagerTabStrip` or the equivalent. Hence, waiting until the user gets all the way to the end to begin loading additional data seems like it would be annoying to the user -- you had all this time to go retrieve more data, but didn't use it.

An alternative, therefore, is for you to register a `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` with your `ViewPager`. When `onPageSelected()`, and you consider yourself to be close to the end, kick off an `AsyncTask` (or whatever) to go gather more data. The catch then is that you will need to update the data used by the `PagerAdapter` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on that adapter once the data has been updated.

Comment: There are of course usecases - especially when the fragments do not actually rely on loading huge amounts of data, but for example the position of the viewpager just reflects an index of what data you look at. For example: I want to have a ViewPager that has a page per day, starting today and extending to the right to - well, infinity, if you wish. Flipping pages just means switching the day to display and the data to display is just calculated, not loaded. I am still not sure how to implement this...

Comment: @Zordid: As I noted in my answer, to create an "infinite" `ViewPager`, you would have to have that logic in your custom `PagerAdapter` implementation. Neither `FragmentPagerAdapter` nor `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` are capable of this, because you will run out of memory, because they will create new fragments for each page.

Comment: Currently I use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, so far I didn't reach a limit. But I was unsure about this because of the saving of the states - my views really don't have a state because each page just reflects a  selected day in the calendar... I guess I should rewrite that again with my custom adapter - or just switch to Views instead of Fragments...

Comment: Don't FragmentPagerAdapter  just get (entirely) rid of fragments it doesn't show ? I think it uses only up to 3 at every time.

Comment: @androiddeveloper: The page limit is a `ViewPager` thing, not a `PagerAdapter` thing. The last time I looked at the `FragmentPagerAdapter` source, it did not get rid of pages, which is the point behind having `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` (which does get rid of pages but holds onto bundles for each one's state).

Comment: @CommonsWare If you remove the fragment correctly using destroyItem (as such: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zAKR.png ) , it will be GC-ed (checked by writing to log on finalize of the fragment), so I don't think there will be memory leak. Weird thing is that it's not implemented this way by default. I tried without this implementation, and I never saw the fragments get GC-ed. I think they never really get removed, even though it seems the code within should handle it ok. Seems like all created ones are in cache. At least it doesn't re-create fragments that you've already visited. :)

Answer (score 6):

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return (Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    //artificially large value for infinite scrolling
}

public int getRealCount(){
//Do something to return the actual number of objects.
}   


@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {  
    int virtualPosition = position % getRealCount();
    return instantiateVirtualItem(container, virtualPosition);
}

public Object instantiateVirtualItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {             
//Do the required part here
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    int virtualPosition = position % getRealCount();
    destroyVirtualItem(container, virtualPosition, object);
}


public void destroyVirtualItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object){
    container.removeView((View) object);            
}
```

Now, the most important part

```
pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(10); //your choice
pager.setCurrentItem(Integer.MAX_VALUE/2,false);
//pager is the ViewPager object
```

PS: I have successfully implemented this. Ask if you still have doubt.

Comment: @stefan do inform here when you find one.

Comment: Guess the only option is to modify ViewPager. For my case, a swipeable calendar, it would also be great to get the item by a DateTime instead of an Integer...

Comment: Hi @Shakti, I tried implementing your approach, but my App will be stuck (Out of memory). I did a similar approach with a RecyclerView, which worked, but osmehow the ViewPager won't. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can 'fake it out' as follows:

You are likely to show a huuuuge number of pages. Use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` class:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html

Implement the `getCount` method by returning `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.
Implement the getItemPosition method by always returning `POSITION_NONE`.
Implement the `getItem` method as you wish, returning the appropriate Fragment.

Then, when the Activity that hosts the ViewPager starts, set the initial position of the ViewPager to a very large number, e.g. `viewPager.setCurrentItem(Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2);`.

I haven't tried this myself..., YMMV! :)

Comment: With Integer.MAX_VALUE, there are performance issues and UI thread is blocked