# Easiest way to implement truly infinite snapping pages in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I know that there are a couple of different Android views I could probably use to implement a truly infinite page scrolling with constantly changing content. However which view does support this kind of behavior the best so I need to change as little code as possible for that? Pager View, Recycler View, Scroll view...?

Any help is very welcome since I don't want to waste too much time implementing a certain view and later realizing that I should have solved it differently.

Comment: This question is too broad and needs more focus. SO is a great forum for figuring out specific problems with implementation but I would recommend another community when seeking broad recommendations and guidelines, as these types of questions tend to draw opinionated responses rather than factual ones.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which swipe(vertically or horizontally) you want.

1. You can try ViewPager. This changes whole layout(Fragments).

   check this out:
   https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide
2. If you need to load successive items like posts, then you need to implement it with ScrollView or RecyclerView/ListView

   check this out: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView

Comment: I really like the effect of the ViewPager, so it is not possible to use this for endless elements like posts? Also I want todo it vertically.

Comment: @StephanPillhofer Well, It basically uses Fragments. If you want to show the list of items little by little such as Facebook or Instagram, then you'd better go for using `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Ok, but it is also pissible to create infinit Fragments in a ViewPager? I kinda want todo something like Facebook with endless posts, but one post should cover the whole page always and snap to it while scrolling. I saw posts when people made a looping ViewPager but can it also be truely infinit? Adding fragments on the go?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446806/endless-adapter-for-viewpager

Comment: Github: https://github.com/search?q=android+infinite+page&type=Repositories